# How do I extract a tag content from XML using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have a XML file of a few thousand records, from which I want to extract:

- The city of tag 110 code c (for example Berlin)
- The library code of tag 110 code g (for example D-Bbbf)

I want would like to get a dataframe of all the cities next to the library code. So for example `df = {'Cities': [Berlin, London], 'Codes': [D-Bbbf, GB-Lna]}`

This is a piece of the XML:

```html
<marc:record>
  <marc:controlfield tag="001">39612</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="003">DE-633</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="005">20161109000000.0</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="008">161109n|||||||a|||              a</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:datafield tag="024" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <marc:subfield code="a">2127361-3</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="2">DNB</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
  <marc:datafield tag="110" ind1="2" ind2=" ">
    <marc:subfield code="a">Bibliothek für Bildungsgeschichtliche Forschung</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="c">Berlin</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="g">D-Bbbf</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
</marc:record><marc:record>
  <marc:controlfield tag="001">30006648</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="003">DE-633</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:controlfield tag="005">20161109000000.0</marc:controlfield>
  <marc:datafield tag="110" ind1="2" ind2=" ">
    <marc:subfield code="a">The National Archives</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="c">London</marc:subfield>
    <marc:subfield code="g">GB-Lna</marc:subfield>
  </marc:datafield>
</marc:record>
```

This is what I have done:

```
city = doc.find(tag="110").find(code="c").get_text()
print(city)
```

This gives be the first city, but I want a list of all the cities. So I tried this

```
# Import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Read the XML file
with open('institutions.xml', 'r') as f_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), 'html.parser')
    
data = []
for record in soup.select(find(tag="110").find(code="c")):
    tag_110 = record.select_one('[tag="110"] > [code="c"]') # select city

    data.append([tag_110.get_text(strip=True)])

print(data)
```

But I unfortunately get an error. Hopefully you could help me! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add them to dictionary as following code:

```
# Import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Data= {'Cities':[],
        'Code':[]}

# Read the XML file
with open('institutions.xml', 'r') as f_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), 'html.parser')
    

for record in soup.find_all(tag="110"):
    City = record.select_one('[code="c"]') # select city
    Code = record.select_one('[code="g"]') # select code
    Data['Cities'].append(City.get_text(strip=True))
    Data['Code'].append(Code.get_text(strip=True))

print(Data)
```

Output:

```
{'Cities': ['Berlin', 'London'], 'Code': ['D-Bbbf', 'GB-Lna']}
```